# How to move from login page to list page?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I am doing  a project on project managment, so I have to show the project details of user once logged in. I'm taking down all the project details in a list so that after login validation, I can get to the project details. But don't know how to call that and plz can someone help me figure out how to store the ID in

```
 //controller
        public static Result login() {
                User user = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest().get();

                 CommonService service = new CommonServiceImpl();

                  boolean response=service.login(user);
                   if(response){
            return ok(welcome.render());
            }
            else{
                return ok("not sucees");
            }
            }
        how to call another method to show project details

        //daoimpl
          public  boolean login(User user)
            {

            try {
                con = JdbcUtil.getSqlConnection();
                VERIFY_USER=select * from project_managment.t_user where email=? and password=?;
                ps = con.prepareStatement(VERIFY_USER);
                ps.setString(1, user.getEmail());
                ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
                 rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    response=true;
                }


            }

            catch (Exception e) {

            }
            finally {
                JdbcUtil.dbResourceCleanUp(rs,ps,con);
            }
            return response;
            }
```

how to call another method to show project details

//user is my model class

```
    public class User {

                int id;
                String firstname;
                String lastname;

                String password;
                String email;
                int phone;
                public int getId() {
                    return id;
                }
                public void setId(int id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }
                public String getFirstname() {
                    return firstname;
                }
                public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
                    this.firstname = firstname;
                }
                public String getLastname() {
                    return lastname;
                }
                public void setLastname(String lastname) {
                    this.lastname = lastname;
                }
                public String getPassword() {
                    return password;
                }
                public void setPassword(String password) {
                    this.password = password;
                }
                public String getEmail() {
                    return email;
                }
                public void setEmail(String email) {
                    this.email = email;
                }
                public int getPhone() {
                    return phone;
                }
                public void setPhone(int phone) {
                    this.phone = phone;
                }


    //projectdetails modelclass
    public class ProjectDetails {

    String ProjectName;
    String StartDate;
    String endDate;
    int hours;
    String mngrName;

    public String getProjectName() {
        return ProjectName;
    }
    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        ProjectName = projectName;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return StartDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        StartDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }
    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    public String getMngrName() {
        return mngrName;
    }
    public void setMngrName(String mngrName) {
        this.mngrName = mngrName;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your answer have a look at [ACTIVITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [ACTIVITY LIFECYCLE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Once you are done with login task, you can finish that `activity` and start new `activity` having list.